# How to scroll vertically in sencha touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I am using sencha touch carousel, in which i am using horizontal swipe. Which works perfect.
But within that i am using panels which i want to scroll vertically(scroll each page to the bottom). How to do that? I have given scroll:'vertical' in each panel as follows:

```
var myFirstPage = Ext.Panel({
      id:'tableId',
          iconCls:'myToolBar',
          style:'overflow:auto;' ,
          scroll:'vertical',
          items:.........});
Ext.setup( {
    onReady: function() {
      myCarouselId = new Ext.Carousel({
        fullscreen: true,
        id:'myCar',

        items : [ myFirstPage]...............});
```

But i cant scroll the panel to the bottom . Where am going wrong?

[Sencha touch vertical scroll content in a horizontal carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530770/sencha-touch-vertical-scroll-content-in-a-horizontal-carousel?rq=1) . Accroding to this stackoverflow answer we can scroll child contents vertically in horizontal carousel , same issue like me. But i am doing the same here , which i cant scroll.
My child panel contains vbox and hbox layout.

Can somebody answer my question ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me and i got it from [sench forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?241175-Vertically-scrolling-panel-within-a-default-horizontal-carousel)

**set the scrollable config in Panel**

```
scrollable : {
      direction     : 'vertical',
      directionLock : true
}
```

**Example**

```
var myFirstPage = Ext.Panel({
          id:'tableId',
          iconCls:'myToolBar',
          scrollable : {
            direction     : 'vertical',
            directionLock : true
         },
        items:.........});

Ext.setup( {
    onReady: function() {
      myCarouselId = new Ext.Carousel({
        fullscreen: true,
        id:'myCar',
        items : [ myFirstPage]...............});
```

see this [fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#UErM1)

Comment: @SSS not for me, i tested see the fiddle i posted in the answer

Comment: i used just a panel with vbox layout (it's default.. no need to specify).. can you create fiddle with you code (as simple as passible) or just update your question with panel items code

Comment: @SSS why you adding toolbar within a toolbar ? your panel code is full of toolbars?

Comment: i don't think you can do that, what you are trying to achieve in that panel?

Comment: I have changed toolbar into container and checked it. It will not work .I think for hbox layout scroll will not work

Comment: change the code in fiddle also.. post the link and let me try.. i didn't understood how you want to design that panel

Comment: @SSS i think my answer is exact for you question.. except that panel you designed.. accepting answer will be appropriate and also helps others who is searching for same problem.

Comment: @SSS The links to senchafiddle.com are broken.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you want 'hbox' usability inside your panels, you need to fit its width inside the container.
If it will need to create scrollbars of its own, it will fail to do so.

What you need is to define scrolling differently:

```
scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock : true
}
```

Like this:

```
    var carousel = Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
fullscreen: true,
items : [ 
    {  xtype: 'panel',     
       scrollable: {
         direction: 'vertical',
         directionLock: true
       },
       html: 'This panel is scrollable!',
       items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'first',
                label: 'First'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'second',
                label: 'Second'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'third',
                label: 'Third'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'first1',
                label: 'First1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'second1',
                label: 'Second1'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'third1',
                label: 'Third1'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'first12',
                label: 'First12'
            },
               { xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                width: 200,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'first-box',
                    label: 'First-box'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'second-box',
                    label: 'Second-box'
                },{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'third-box',
                    label: 'Third-box'
                }]
           }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'second12',
                label: 'Second12'
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'third12',
                label: 'Third12'
            }]
    }, {
       xtype: 'panel',
       scroll:'vertical',  // will not work
       html: 'This panel is not scrollable!',
    }]
});
```

You can try this within any live preview of [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.scroll.Scroller-event-scroll)
Hope this helps

Comment: yeah it will scroll but once i leave my finger it will go back to original position

Comment: @SSS I edited my answer to comply with 'hbox' needs. It works well if outside the bounds of a device.